# Access data relationship confusion

Tags: ms-access, etl

one of our ETL jobs uses it's source data from Access DB. I recently was trying to investigate the set up of this whole job as we were thinking there may need to be some changes made due to new user requirements.

When I looked at the data source in Data Services (right click > view data) I noticed one of the columns (Column D in Table A) had ID type numbers in it and was set to INT, but in the actual access database it has Names and general text in it however the field is set to a number type.

I only realised what was happening when I noticed in the each row of this data in Access there was a drop down button and it displayed like a view of data with 3 columns. I then found the relationship button while looking at the table design.

I noticed that the data being displayed in Access was actually from a column in a different table lets say Column E in Table B, but one that has relationship from table A.

So my question is, how did this other table's column data (Column E, Table B) get set to show in Table A, Column D as there are many other columns to pick. The only way I can see how to pick that data is from the drop down view, manually, one at a time for each row. I don't think anyone would be prepared to sit and do that to multiple thousands of rows.

The drop down view has 3 columns from Table B. Why those columns and why not all of them if the table B and A are joined by ID?

Thanks

Andrew

Comment: Thou shalt abhor the use of "Lookup Fields" which art the creation of the Evil One. (http://access.mvps.org/access/tencommandments.htm).   I think that's what you've got, and hopefully not multi-value fields.  If you go into the table design and select the `Lookup` tab on the `Field Properties` it will say `Combo Box` along with column count of >1 and some SQL in the `Row Source`.  Change the `Display Control` to Text Box and it should show the Foreign Key value.

Comment: @vwegert thanks that is very helpful I see how it is done now. I had no hand in the original design and have never used Access in this manner before so that clears it up. Thanks again. Andrew

Comment: Thanks @vwegert.  :)  Shall I add it as an answer then?

Comment: Please stop paging me, I have nothing to do with this question (besides removing a misplaced tag) :-)